# Backbone model not getting updated

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have this model in backbone app:

```
var dimensions = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        a: 10,
        f: 1,
        g: 1
    }
});
```

Then I'm updating this model data from server using model.fetch(); which is returning following:

```
{
    f: 10,
    g: 2,
    h: 3            
}
```

It seems like mode is not getting updated as it is still giving me following output :

```
dimensions.get('a'); //10;
```

Comment: `model.clear().fetch()` will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting expected result, `model.fetch();` will not clear out your model, but rather `extends` the attributes of your `model`. So, after fetch your model looks like this:

```
{
    a: 10,
    f: 10,
    g: 2,
    h: 3
}
```

That's why you are getting 10 for `a`. You can use  `dimentions.clear();` is you intend to clear model attributes.